# How to remove images from body field in views?

Tags: views, nodes, media

In the body field of a content type, I have added an image at the start. In my view, I want to show 200 characters from the body field. It also prints the image.

How can I skip the photos from the body field in the view, and print just the text?

Comment: Are you using the teaser version of the body in your View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the Body Field `Rewrite results` in your Views and enable the option **Strip HTML tags**. Use `Preserve certain tags` if you have other elements within your text you want to show, enter them there.

This option is below the `Trim this field to a maximum number of characters` you're probably using, you'll probably want to also use the suboption `Field can contain HTML`.

Comment: Easy and best solution for my issue. Thanx